# Template Haskell in GHCI

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ghci

I'm new at learning Haskell so I'll say sorry in advance for the silly questions.
I want to build a function that removes all the upper cases from a string (I use GHCI)

```
removeUppercase st = [c| c<-st, c 'elem' ['A..'Z']]
```

But when I compile it, it shows the following message:

```
Syntax error on 'elem' 
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
In the Template Haskell quotation 'elem'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You used an apostrophe `'`, where you should have used a backtick `\``. Also, you're missing a closing single quote: `[c | c <- st, c \`elem\` ['A' .. 'Z']]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used an apostrophe `'`, where you should have used a backtick `` ` ``. Also, you're missing a closing single quote:

```
removeUppercase st = [c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A' .. 'Z']]
```

Note that your function is the same as

```
removeUppercase = filter (`elem` ['A' .. 'Z'])
```

<sup>*This answer is a community answer since the actual question doesn't seem on-topic for StackOverflow, as the error origins from a typographical mistake.*</sup>